# Minify dynamic php stylesheets

Tags: php, css, dynamic, stylesheet, minify

So I have been using [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) to compress my JS and CSS which had all been going nicely until I needed to compress some dynamic php stylesheets.

I tried to use htaccess to fool it into thinking it was a css file, but I then realised it uses absolute file paths which would not be effected by mod_rewrite

Anyways whenever I point it at a php file, it always returns '400 Bad Request'. Any idea on how to solve this other than writing my own compression script?

Comment: what is dynamic php stylesheet?

Comment: So you want to use a tool that works with flat files to compress something that's being created dynamically. Doesn't that sound a bit.. impossible to you? :)

Comment: I am adding this as a comment as it is a stab in the dark: Try making a static css file, then inside there including the dynamic one with the @import statement, then minify the static one. If it works, let me know I'll add it as an answer ;) BTW, I know you are supposed to avoid @import, but hey.

Comment: yeah def trying to avoid @import, have way too many http requests atm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find the best way to deal with minifying and compressing stylesheets is to do it yourself. Check out this code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))." GMT");
header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', (filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) + 691200))." GMT");

//This GZIPs the CSS for transmission to the user
//making file size smaller and transfer rate quicker
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
ob_start("compress");

//Function for compressing the CSS as tightly as possible
function compress($buffer) {
    //Remove CSS comments
    $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);
    //Remove tabs, spaces, newlines, etc.
    $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}

//Main style
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/templates/style/style.css");

//Other style
if($php_variable) {
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/templates/style/other.css");
}

ob_end_flush();
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

There's a lot of things going on here, so let me explain.

**Headers**

- Setting the file type as being CSS.
- Setting the `Last-Modified` and `Expires` header for cache control (Setting at slightly over a week, you can change this).

**Minify and GZIP**

- Using `ob_start`, we tell it to GZIP this file as well as run a custom function `compress`.
- `compress` removes all CSS comments and white space when sending to to the browser. This means you can keep all your comments and spacing the way you like it in your source files for easier editing, but only send the bare minimum to the browser.

**Style**

- Using `require` to import the stylesheets. Do this for as many stylesheets as you'd like; They'll all get delivered in a single HTTP request to the user.

**Using Your New File**

You'll call on the file just as you would a normal CSS file.

```
<style type="text/css" src="/path/to/css-script.php"></style>
```

**Conclusion**

Using this method, you're doing several awesome things.

- Provides the correct headers for cache'ing, making return visits to your site quick.
- Minifys all the contents to contain no extra white space or comments.
- Compresses the file using GZIP for smaller file size.
- Includes all your stylesheets in one HTTP request, great for optimization.
- Avoids using `@import` statements...which in itself is awesome.
- Allows you to keep multiple stylesheets and use PHP logic to include or not include them.
- Allows you to keep your source stylesheets spaced and commented as you like with no consequence to the visitors.

You can use this same method for JavaScript as well, though the `compress` function above is strictly for CSS so I would omit it.

Use this technique in combination with this cache control technique, and you've built yourself an awesome CSS/JS handler: [How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files/118886#118886)

Comment: I'll have to adapt this a little myself. Minify is really slow with CSS.

Comment: Hah perfect answer, nice one chap :) Wish I could give you bonus point for excessive use of the word awesome :P

Comment: just to note, wont work with safari as is due to lack of gzip support